# Combining two components

Tags: delphi

I created a component combining TPanel and TDBNavigator

```
Constructor TsDBNavPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
Begin
  Inherited Create(AOwner);
  sDBNavigator:= TDBNavigator.Create(Self);
  sDBNavigator.Parent:= Self;
  sDBNavigator.align:= alLeft;
End;
```

It works on runtime, however design time DBNavigator is not visible.
What I am missing?

Comment: Try calling `sDBNavigator.SetSubComponent(True)`

Comment: Thank you
It solved my problem